# RabbitMQ fails to start

Tags: windows, rabbitmq

The RabbitMQ windows service will not start:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.0.4\sbin>rabbitmq-service.bat start
C:\Program Files (x86)\erl5.10.1\erts-5.10.1\bin\erlsrv: Failed to start service RabbitMQ.
Error: The process terminated unexpectedly.
```

I can run rabbitmq-server.bat without any problems.

No log entries are made to %appdata%\RabbitMQ\log\ directory when trying to start the service.

How to make it work?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Problem solved!

My IT department has mapped %appdata% to a network share and it seems that the RabbitMQ scripts can’t work with that.

I solved the problem this way: Set the environment variable “RABBITMQ_BASE” to “c:\rabbitmq”, uninstall the service (rabbitmq-service.bat remove) and install the service again (rabbitmq-service.bat install).

Comment: I had my own issues with this, and setting the environment variable RABBITMQ_SERVER to the installed dir and reinstalling the service worked for me.

Answer (score 53):

I faced the same problem and was able to solve the problem following the steps mentioned below.

1. Run the command prompt as Administrator
2. Navigate to the sbin directory and uninstall the service. rabbitmq-service remove
3. Reinstall the service rabbitmq-service install
4. Enable the plugins. rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
5. Start the service rabbitmq-service start
6. Go to "http://localhost:15672/"

Comment: Thanks. Additionally, for me, on windows, it was forgetting to add ERLANG_HOME to system variable. https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-windows-manual.html

Comment: I had to restart a couple of times, add RABBITMQ_BASE and RABBITMQ_SERVER (path to install dir of RabbitMQ) to Environment Variables.

Answer (score 5):

**- check Erlang compatability with RabbitMQ**

** Installtion

- Install Erlang
- Install Rabbit_MQ
- Set system variables

**Set Environment variable-**

- RABBITMQ_BASE  c:\RabbitMQ Server
- ERLANG_HOME  C:\Program Files\erl10.7

**Config MQ Server**

- stop RabbitMq : rabbitmq-service.bat stop
- Enable management  : rabbitmq-plugins.bat enable rabbitmq_management
- Reinstall server : rabbitmq-service.bat install
- Start Server : rabbitmq-service.bat start
- Start App : rabbitmqctl.bat start_app
- Open Brower :  http://localhost:15672  user guest / guest

**Add new User**

- List users : rabbitmqctl.bat list_users
- Add new user :  rabbitmqctl.bat add_user user1 pass1
- Give administrator privileges : rabbitmqctl.bat set_user_tags user1

Answer (score 4):

I restarted my computer after install and things are running a lot smoother

Answer (score 4):

In my case helped running console as an administrator

Answer (score 4):

Deleting "AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ" solved this problem for me

Answer (score 3):

Deleting `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Ericsson\Erlang\ErlSrv\1.1\RabbitMQ` folder from Registry has solved the problem for me. I have to reinstall (uninstall and install) the RabbitMQ after deleting the registry.

Moreover, I have deleted `C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ` earlier.

I have found the solution from a [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rabbitmq-users/68R7qRtboY4) of a google group.

Answer (score 1):

My situation was caused by wrong Erlang version. I solved it by the following steps:

1. Uninstall the older version Erlang
2. Install the newly version Erlang accordding to https://www.rabbitmq.com/which-erlang.html
3. Reinstall RabbitMQ
4. Install RabbitMQ plugin by opening the Windows's cmd and switch to the sbin directory eg.`Your-Path\rabbitmq_server-3.7.13\sbin` and execute the command `rabbitmq-plugins.bat enable rabbitmq_management`
5. Start RabbitMQ and visit http://localhost:15672/

Answer (score 1):

None of the suggestions in this thread helped me and looks like I had a different issue. So what I figured out, after power outage our Rabbit stopped starting with the same error.

After some research I already wanted to reinstall RabbitMQ and Erlang like many others did in this thread but then I decided to spend a bit more time to figure out what could be the real reason...

I could literally do nothing. Couldn't get crash dump to get any ideas what could be wrong. So I decided to try to start server manually with `./rabbitmq-server.bat` command. In order to do that open CMD with Admin privileges and go to `sbin` folder `C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.7.14\sbin`
and start it from there. And voilà! I got this error message
[image]

Have no idea what could happen with the library and what was the reason why it disappeared but after installing VS C++ Redistributable package from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170#visual-studio-2013-vc-120 and RabbitMQ is back to live!

In my case I installed Visual Studio 2013 (VC++ 12.0) but it may be different in your case depending on Rabbit version you use.

And it's definitely better and faster option than reinstalling RabbitMQ and Erlang!

Answer (score 0):

How I solved the same issue... Reinstalled Erlang from x86 to x64. Also checked the option to install Microsoft distributed dlls. I don't know which one of two helped me but it helped at least.

Answer (score 0):

run the following command after installation rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management on rabbit mq path`RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.6.9\sbin>rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management`

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue of 1067 error in Windows 10. It turns out the rabbitmq config file in location `C:\Users\IPS\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ\advanced.config` was having some syntax error. It was changed from the default configuration. Also, the `rabbitmq.conf` file at the same location also had a syntax error. I removed the `rabbitmq.conf` file and removed the changes from the `advanced.config` file. After that ranbbitmq service started without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I have also come across similar problem, but found that the problem due to folder named "Program" in the OS drive.

[Reference.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-files/there-is-a-file-or-folder-called-cprogram-which/72e7f311-c6f2-45ee-a5a3-3457ea179f6d)

Answer (score 0):

I renamed my computer and restart. Then everything works fine. I guess Chinese characters effect the rabbit service.

old name: 孙
new name: adam

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything mentioned above. Nothing worked for me. I figured out that Erlang and RabbitMQ version should be compatible for it to work fine.
Take a look here https://www.rabbitmq.com/which-erlang.html.

Just uninstall Erlang and RabbitMQ from your system and install the compatible versions.

Answer (score 0):

After attempting to run RabbitMQ commands through CMD (hint, sbin dir can be launched directly from RabbitMQ Server in the start menu in Windows) I got the error Unable to load emulator (beam.smp.dll)

I reinstalled my version of ERLang (windows dir C:/Program Files/erl.VERSION NUMBER) and the service started right up without issues.

Answer (score 0):

Another weird answer to the pile:

After upgrading Erlang OTP, the old versions (10.5, 15.2.2, and 15.2.2.5) did not cleanly uninstall and left files behind in c:\Program Files. I was unable to delete the files manually due to erlsrv.exe being "open in Windows Event Viewer" (wtf?). I had to use msconfig to restart the system to safe mode with networking and delete the file. After a normal restart and reinstalling Erlang OTP and RabbitMQ things were back to normal.